# 'that' vs. 'which'/'who' when multiple noun phrases are involved

Tags: ambiguity, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, antecedents

The sentences at issue are:

> "The company required a way to showcase their product line and its benefits that can not be typically highlighted in a traditional TV commercial."

> "He points to the picture of several girls and a few boys that are holding some apples"

My question is: **Is the use of "that" here intentional** due to its property to modify both "their product line and its benefits" and "several girls and a few boys" as a single antecedent? In other words, would using "which" in the 1st sentence and "who" in the 2nd one instead of "that" result in only the more adjacent noun phrase to the relative pronoun ("its benefits" and "a few boys") being modified?

Also, I have searched the Internet but failed to find the appropriate term for this grammatical function of "that" in disambiguating relative clauses with multiple noun phrases (even the keywords "disambiguation antecedents with relative pronouns" yielded no relevant results). Most articles or guidelines simply focus on how "that" is used in restrictive relative clauses while "which" can be used in nonrestrictive ones.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The pronouns "which", "that", and "who" can all be either singular or plural, so can you explain why you think that using one vs. another might make a difference in whether it refers to one or multiple antecedents?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I just feel that the author uses "that" intentionally to reflect that (for sentence 1) neither the product line nor its associated benefits is highlighted by traditional TV advertising, rather than just the benefits alone. This question aimed to get a confirmation whether the relative pronoun "that" actually has a "hidden" property to modify noun phrases more inclusively than "which/who", that, if true, is very scarcely mentioned in textbooks and academic materials. But apparently I was in the wrong and there is no such difference between "that" and the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer focuses on the second example, as I find there is a greater potential for ambiguity. Who are holding the apples in the picture, *the girls and a few boys* or only *a few boys*?

> i. He points to the picture of several girls and a few boys **that** are holding some apples.
> ii. He points to the picture of several girls, **and a few boys** that are holding some apples.
> iii. He points to the picture of several girls and a few boys **who** are holding some apples.

If there was a comma separating the objects of the [prepositional phrase](https://www.thoughtco.com/prepositional-phrase-1691663) that is modifying the subject `the picture` —  "of several girls" and "a few boys holding apples" (ii) then the reader might infer only the boys in the picture were holding apples. However, there is no comma in the original sentence (i) which suggests "several girls and a few boys holding apples" is most likely to be considered as the single antecedent of *that*. Also, the antecedent would not change if *who* substituted *that* in the integrated/restricted clause, as long as there was no comma separating [the object of the prepositional phrase](https://www.thoughtco.com/object-of-a-preposition-op-1691447): *several girls and a few boys*  (iii).